# PowerShell Nested Loop inner Loop doesnt work?

Tags: powershell, shell, loops, nested-loops

Hi first Question on PowerShell,

I need to write a script that takes a log file and do some calculation in it.

I am reading the log file correctly and then I am creating two arrays that only contain the lines that I need from the file.

```
$inVar = Select-String -path C:\Dev\Script\Ldorado.log  -pattern "IN:"             
$outVar = Select-String -path C:\Dev\Script\Ldorado.log -pattern "OUT:"
```

I get back every line where there is an IN in 1 array and OUT in the other.

I managed to split the lines to only get the dates in each line - by using `.Lines.Split("(")`

If I have the two date values from the array I can calc the timespan with `New-TimeSpan` and some converting.

Now I need to somehow do this for every entry there is inside the file that matches the pattern, so I think I need a Loop or even a nested Loop. I tried every Loop (for / foreach / foreachObject / while...) but with no luck.

For example if you look at this code:

```
foreach ($out in $outVar) {
$testVar = $out.Line.Split("(")[0]
    foreach ($in in $inVar) {
        $testIn = $in.Line.Split("(")[0]
    }
    Write-Host $testVar + $testIn
}
```

my Output looks like this:

```
12:55:49  + 13:20:31 
12:55:49  + 13:20:31 
12:55:49  + 13:20:31 
13:54:35  + 13:20:31 
13:54:35  + 13:20:31 
13:54:35  + 13:20:31 
16:37:44  + 13:20:31 
16:37:44  + 13:20:31 
16:37:44  + 13:20:31 
17:15:23  + 13:20:31 
17:15:23  + 13:20:31 
17:15:23  + 13:20:31 
 9:06:13  + 13:20:31 
 9:06:13  + 13:20:31 
 ...
```

Having every value 3 times is correct because there are always IN's and 3OUT's for every log.

The outer loop seems to work correctly but the nested Loop just takes the last value there is and prints it - instead I want to have the same behavior as the outer loop where it actually loops.

Anyone knows how I can solve this?

Comment: Try moving the `Write-Host` call into the inner loop.

Comment: @mklement0 is right. The reason only one `$testIn` gets written is because `write-host` is outside the nested `foreach` loop, and therefore only runs when that loop is complete.

Comment: Moving the write-host call inside the nested for loop doenst solve my problem. By doing so the outer loop repeats every entry for every entry that my inner loop has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop so you can grab the values at the same index from each array (this assumes `$outVar` and `$inVar` are aligned and of the same length):

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $outVar.Length; $i++) {
    $testVar = $outVar[$i].Line.Split("(")[0]
    $testIn  = $inVar[$i].Line.Split("(")[0]
    Write-Host $testVar + $testIn
}
```

Comment: Pretty simple and works as long as I always have the same amount of Outs and Ins gonna go with that atm - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the results into arrays then output them in the desired format. Like the following

```
#Empty arrays
$testIn_arr = @()
$testVar_arr = @()
foreach ($out in $outVar) {
$testVar = $out.Line.Split("(")[0]
$testVar_arr += @($testVar)
}

foreach ($in in $inVar) {
$testIn = $in.Line.Split("(")[0]
$testIn_arr += @($testIn)
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $testIn_arr.Count; $i++)
{
 Write-Host $($testVar_arr[$i]) + "+" + $($testIn_arr[$i])
}
```

Comment: Not bad gonna look into it - your Write-Host however prints the "+" 3 times :D